# Indexing issue - keep reverting to manual

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, indexing, reindex

With our Magento version 1.9.1.0 we are having an issue where indexing reverts back to manual as can be seen here
[image]

We set the mode to 'Update on Save' and do indexing via command line and it all shows green, but after sometime it some indexes reverts back to 'Manual'. Not sure what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once do re indexing pro-grammatically this way:

```
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
   $index->reindexAll();
}
```

Then see if it fixed.

Comment: Excellent! it fixed a long time issue. May I know what was wrong while I tried before to reindex -all via shell but it was keep reverting back?

Comment: It seems like that after some weeks of working fine, the same issue has come again and and code is no longer helping now... it again reverts back itself to manual. Can you please help?